# Auto-Publishing from Integromat into Linked: Can't Share an Image Post

Tags: linkedin-api, airtable, make.com

The documentation is limited on the Linkedin integration on Integromat: https://support.integromat.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006248613-LinkedIn

I can upload a text post just fine, but uploading an Image Post is giving me trouble.

What data is it expecting for:

- file name (this seems self-explanatory but I get a Null error)
- data (I tried using the image URL but this didn't work)

Thanks for the help[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

to get this to work, all we need to do is add the "HTTP" tool and map the image

Comment: Sorry, this still doesn't work. I get this error message: 
---------
DataError

null
Origin

LinkedIn
Description

No description available.
Automatic error handler

If you want to handle this error automatically, choose one of the following options. This will create a new error-handler route in your scenario. You can then expand the route in any way you like.
----------------